# What's the path to files in myapp/static on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I want to add objects based on information of a .csv file (call it info.csv) to my models when the project is initiated on Google appengine (I'm using django-nonrel).
My approach is to write a dedicated util.py in myapp, which is called in `view.py`. `util.py` is supposed to read `info.csv` and initiate objects in the databse.

However, it gives `"No such file or directory: ...`" error. Putting the file in `myapp/static folder` causes other problem.

How do I go about this? Is there more clever way to tackle this problem? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

> For efficiency, App Engine stores and serves static files separately
>   from application files. **Static files are not available in the
>   application's file system**. If you have data files that need to be read
>   by the application code, the data files must be application files, and
>   must not be matched by a static file pattern.

Reference [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers)

To access your file, save it in the same directory of your script and access it through something like this:

```
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'info.csv')
your_file = open(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen and used this design pattern:

in config.py:

```
INFO: [a,b,c] #or whatever would otherwise go in info.csv
```

in views.py:

```
import config

your_data = config.INFO
```